# How to implement SharedPreferences in my game

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my GamePanel.java class I have an integer "best" which is meant to record the highest score on the game.But each time I close and reopen my game the value resets to zero.
I have no idea on how to implement the SharedPreferences on my game.Here is the relevant part of my **GamePanel.Java**

```
public class GamePanel extends GLSurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
private int best;

public void update() {

if(player.getScore()>best) {
        best = player.getScore();
    }
}
}
public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255,211,38));
    paint.setTextSize(15);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("FUEL: " + distance, 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("BEST: " + best, WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("SCORE: " + player.getScore(), 350, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
```

How do I use SharedPreferences to save the int "best"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setBestScore() and getBestScore() to save and get best score from shared preferences respectively.

```
private void setBestScore(int bestScore) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getContext().getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("bestScore", bestScore);
    editor.apply();
}

private int getBestScore() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("gamepanel", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getInt("bestScore", 0);
}
```

In update()

```
if(player.getScore() > getBestScore()) {
    setBestScore(player.getScore());
}
```

You have to save best score when you play game for the first time.

Comment: there is no error code the game runs but the score still resets on close

Comment: Are you calling setBestScore when you open the app for the first time (freshly installed)?

Comment: I don't think so, how should i do that?

Comment: i have uploaded it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136620/discussion-between-kennedy-and-sanyam-jain).

Comment: could you go back to chat?

Answer (score 0):

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
public void update() 
{
    String MY_PREFS_NAME = "best_score";

    if(player.getScore()>best) 
    {
        best = player.getScore();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("best", ""+best);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
public String getBestScore()
{
    String MY_PREFS_NAME = "best_score";

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String bestScore = prefs.getString("best", "");

    return bestScore;
}
```

more info:

**[Using Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)**

**[Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**

Comment: wherever you want to get best score just call `getBestScore()` method. see my updated answer.

Comment: i added your code,but it doesn't work getSharedPrefrences is highlighted red